# Calculating Log-returns for Multiple Securities in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, quantitative-finance

here's what I have thus far - I have built a price table (as shown in the image), and I would like to calculate the log-returns of the respective tickers. [image: Price Table]
    priceData = pd.read_excel(r'..\PriceData.xlsx', skiprows=range(1),

```
usecols = 'B:SN', index_col = 0)

priceData = priceData.drop(priceData.index[[0,1]])

priceData.index.names = ['Date']

priceData.index = priceData.index.map(pd.to_datetime)

priceData.sort_index()

# To adjust all time series data to start from 1990-01-25 to 2018-09-24
for column in priceData.columns:
    if np.isnan(priceData[column].iloc[0]):
        priceData = priceData.drop([column],axis=1, inplace=True)

stocks = list(table)

returns = table.apply(lambda x: np.log(x)-np.log(x.shift(1)))
```

*table is my dataframe name.

The error message I have faced is:

> "TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and >'datetime.datetime'", 'occurred at index LYB UN Equity')"

## Update

I have tried with:

```
returns = table.apply(lambda x: np.log(x)-np.log(x.shift(1)))
```

But I am met with a new error message:

> ("'float' object has no attribute 'log'", 'occurred at index LYB UN Equity')

Please advise!

Comment: Hi @mikkola, I have added in the error message. Thank you!

Comment: When you call `.shift()` without an `axis` parameter, it defaults to row-wise shifting, which means for your first calculation, you're trying to divide `2018-09-27` by `104.05` which is a meaningless operation

Comment: @G.Anderson thank you for your reply! How can I include the axis parameter in this case?

Comment: From [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html): `df.shift(1, axis=1)`. I would check the documentation there, there are also period and frequency parameters that may be relevant to your project

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out a more intuitive way.

```
# Calculate returns
returns = table.pct_change() # simple linear returns
log_rets = np.log(1+returns)
```

This will work when calculating log returns of multiple securities in the same dataframe. Cheers!